# CSS formatting not indenting second row of an ng-repeat output

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Trying to obtain the following format for output from script:
Days of operation:

```
                Sunday:     Closed
                Monday:     8am - 9am
                            9am - 10am
                Tuesday:    8am - 9am
                            9am - 12pm
                Wednesday:  8am - 9am
                Thursday:   9am - 10am
                            11am - 12pm
```

… and so on.  Instead, output ends up like this:

```
Days of operation:  
                    Sunday:     Closed 
                    Monday:     8am - 9am  
                    9am - 10am
                    Tuesday:    8am - 9am
                    9am - 12pm
                    Wednesday:  8am - 9am
                    Thursday:   9am - 10am
                    11am - 12pm
```

Could use some help to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly with the layout piece that's preventing me from getting the desired result. Here's the code I have in my index.css for formatting:

```
#details label{
  width: 240px;
}
#details .hours-layout{
    float: left;
    width: 100px
}
.label-left {
  float: left;
}
.content-right {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's the code from my html script:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="details">
                    <div class="content">
                      <div><label class="label-left">{{listing_ctrl.COMMON.facilityType}}:</label><span class="content-right">{{ listing_ctrl.listing.program }}</span></div>
                      <div><label class="label-left">{{listing_ctrl.COMMON.facilityOpened}}:</label><span class="content-right">{{ listing_ctrl.listing.dateFounded ? (listing_ctrl.listing.dateFounded | date:'MM/dd/yyyy':'+0') : "Not Available" }}</span></div>
                      <div><label class="label-left">{{listing_ctrl.COMMON.capacity}}:</label><span class="content-right">{{ listing_ctrl.listing.capacity }}</span></div>
<!--New lines v2-->
                      <div ng-switch="listing.rawData.opHoursAvailable">
                            <div ng-switch-when = "N"><label class="label-lelft">{{listing_ctrl.COMMON.hoursOfOp}}:</label><class="content-right">Not available</div>
                            <div ng-switch-default>
                                <p><label class="label-left">{{listing_ctrl.COMMON.hoursOfOp}}:</label><span class="content-right">
                                        <span ng-if="listing_ctrl.listing.operatingHours">
                                            <span ng-repeat="day in listing.operatingHours">
                                                <span class="hours-layout">{{day.day}}:</span>
                                                    <span ng-repeat="sched in day.sched">
                                                        <span ng-switch = "sched.open">
                                                            <span ng-switch-when = "">
                                                                Closed <br/>
                                                            </span>
                                                            <span ng-switch-default class="hours-layout2">
                                                                {{sched.open}} - {{sched.close}}<br/>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I see a few errors in your HTML - did you paste that in or type it in? For example, you have `class="label-lelft"`, a `<class>` element with no closing tag (is that even valid HTML element?), and you have defined CSS for a `details` ID, but I don't see an element with that ID. How about creating a working code snippet in your question that demonstrates where you're at?

Comment: @Lex: I've attached a few more lines of code which shows id "details" in a div element (first line in my html code).  Also fixed the typo from my code which you pointed out.  The classes utilized in this code represent defined classes in my css file for formatting purposes.  Does this provide a better sense of where I'm at and what I'm trying to accomplish?  Even tried playing with ng-style, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Are you using (or have you considered using) any type of layout framework such as Bootstrap?

Comment: @Lex: No. Not familiar with bootstrap at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interpolation within the `style` attribute to set your margin on the second (and third, fourth...) items in your `ng-repeat`. Putting the pieces together from the comments and answers here is your working solution. The reason you have to use a `<div>` instead of a `<span>` is that `<span>` tags cannot use margin or height `style` settings. Personally, I always prefer to use `<div>` elements for positioning. I typically only use `<span>` along with `ng-if` to display conditional text or to apply font/text styles to a word or two in a longer string of text.

```
<div ng-repeat="sched in day.sched">
   <div ng-switch = "sched.open">
          <div ng-switch-when = "">
                Closed
          </div>
          <div ng-switch-default style="{{ $index > 0 ? 'margin-left : 100 px' : '' }}">
               {{sched.open}} - {{sched.close}}
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I asked about Bootstrap is because this becomes a little cleaner when you use a layout framework. Bootsrap (and Material) use row/column type layouts which makes achieving what you're after easier and responsive. When you need to offset your hours you simply add an `offset` class using `ng-class`. Personally, I find this approach much cleaner than using interpolation within the `style` attribute.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="sched in day.sched">
   <div ng-switch = "sched.open">
          <div class="col-xs-6" ng-switch-when = "">
                Closed
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6" ng-switch-default ng-class="{'col-xs-offset-6': $index > 0}">
               {{sched.open}} - {{sched.close}}
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know.  The bootstrap alternative hasn't worked yet for me - it indents the second row (where index > 0) further out than the first row.  Not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

some thing like the following should help you.

```
<span ng-repeat="sched in day.sched">
   <span ng-switch = "sched.open">
          <span ng-switch-when = "">
                Closed <br/>
          </span>
          <span ng-switch-default class="hours-layout2" ng-style="$index > 1 && margin-left : 100 px">
               {{sched.open}} - {{sched.close}}<br/>
          </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Explaination : you can achieve conditional formatting using ng-style. More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: This didn't do the trick.  Is there something else I need to do with the $index?  Also, the class "hours-layout2" has been removed - it was just an empty class and accidentally left in.  Appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $index > 0

Comment: Already tried that.  Didn't work either.  Is it possible that something else is overwriting ng-style?

Comment: I don't think you can use `ng-style` like that. It expects a collection of key/value pairs. What you could do, though, is use interpolation in the `style` attribute. Something like `style="{{ $index > 0 ? 'margin-left: 100px;' : '' }}"`.

Comment: @Lex: Bravo Lex!  Your solution worked perfectly.  But I had to change <span> in the following line to <div> (and corresponding </span> in the code below to </div>) for your suggestion to work (don't understand why span vs. div would make a difference, but it does): <p><label class="label-left">{{listing_ctrl.COMMON.hoursOfOp}}:</label><span class="content-right">

Would it make sense for you to put this as the answer so other folks have an easier time locating the right response as opposed to reading through comments?